# Determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix whose $jk$-th entry is $1/\min\{j,k\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, examples-counterexamples

So on my exam I got a True/False question that asked the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAGbU.jpg):

> For any $n\in\mathbb N$, compute the determinant of the matrix
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1&1&\cdots&1
> \\1&1/2&1/2&\cdots&1/2
> \\1&1/2&1/3&\cdots&1/3
> \\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots
> \\1&1/2&1/3&\cdots&1/n
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> This is the $n\times n$ matrix whose $jk$-th entry is $1/\min\{j,k\}$.

I recognize there has to be some formula that makes calculating the determinant easier, but I'm confused as to what it is.

Comment: One formula would by $\det=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{(n!)^2}$, but then you should just happen to know that one...

Comment: I don't actually, would you care to explain how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any given $n\in\Bbb{N}$ denote the matrix by $A_n$. For $n\geq 2$, applying Laplace expansion along the last row and starting at the bottom right (the entry $\frac{1}{n}$) an working right to left yields
$$\det A_n=\frac{1}{n}\det A_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\det A_{n-1}=-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\det A_{n-1},$$
because the subdeterminants at the coefficients $\frac{1}{1}$ through $\frac{1}{n-2}$ are all zero; removing the $k$-th column makes the rows $k-1$, $k$ and $k+1$ linearly dependent. Of course $\det A_1=1$ so
$$\det A_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n!(n-1)!}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{(n!)^2}.$$

Comment: It should read $\det A_{n-1}$ instead of $\det(A_n)$ on the right of the first formula.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Corrected, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take $n=4$ for simplicity of exposition. We develop against the last line:
$$-\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{vmatrix}
+\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{vmatrix}
-\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 & 1/3
\end{vmatrix}
+\dfrac{1}{4}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 & 1/3
\end{vmatrix}$$
The first determinant is $0$ (two proportional lines), the second is $0$ (two identical columns) the last two are the same and equal the original determinant in size $n-1=3$. This shows that
$$D_4=-\dfrac{1}{12}D_3$$
if $D_n$ is the determinant of your $n\times n$ matrix.
You can generalize these calculations to prove that
$$D_{n+1}=-\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}D_n$$
Together with $D_1=1$ this is enough to find a general formula for $D_n$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out later that this was another way that we could do the problem, along with row reducing and making the matrix triangular and computing the determinant from there.